# git pull to a detached head

Tags: git, jenkins

I do a git clone in Jenkins.

then in my scripts I run the following command:

```
git pull --recurse-submodules
```

which pulls from the submodules.

unfortunately, I get the error:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>
```

How do I have Jenkins pull to the detached head from master? I want to make sure whatever changes are on master are also on the detached Head.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to pull to the detached head from master using the following command:

```
git pull . master
```

or if the master branch resides in a remote repository:

```
git pull . origin/master
```

so I believe that you might specifically want to try:

```
git pull --recurse-submodules . master
```

or

```
git pull --recurse-submodules . origin/master
```

Comment: I run git submodule update --init --recursive afterwards? Is that the right thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a branch rather than checking out a detached head?  Just add `-b newbranch` to the end of your `git checkout` command.  For example:

```
git checkout <hash> -b newbranch
```

This might be enough to solve your problem.  If you don't want to keep the branch around, you can always delete it later using `git branch -D newbranch`

Comment: gotcha.  I just added another answer that explains how to pull into a detached head (using the '.' operator)

Comment: Why would Jenkins need to pull on the submodules?